# How to use query option with aws eks get-token

Tags: aws-cli, amazon-eks

I am trying to get token data only from `aws eks get-token` without any additional tools, like `jq`.

```
aws eks get-token --cluster-name myclustername --query status.token
```

still returns the complete response.

What is wrong with my `--query`? Or does this option not work with this subcommand?

```
aws --version
aws-cli/1.16.218 Python/3.6.8 Linux/4.15.0-1047-aws botocore/1.12.208
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage it looks like it is not possible to use query parameter even with the latest version of awscli 1.16.230. Jq is probably the best tool to use to get the output to Json format and parse it.

However, you may consider using grep and/or sed to output the token value.

I personally think it might be just a bug and it will get fixed with later version of awscli.

Comment: Thank you. I opened the issue https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/4490

Comment: @Sygyzmundovych looks like they marked the issue as enhancement which means it will be enabled soon.